# Phonegap Device Video Picker

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am looking into docs.phonegap.com and found no function that would open up video gallery for user to pick any video and send binary data back to callback function. Is there any?

Have someone written something like that already?

After first answer, I tried following code of Phonegap but it just shows picker which has photos and no videos at all.

```
var opts = {
    sourceType : 0 | 2,
    MediaType : Camera.MediaType.VIDEO // here is error. it's mediaType not MediaType
};

navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onVideoSelected, function(msg) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Oops!', 'You picked no video.');
    return false;
}, opts);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera 
You can pass in the Camera.MediaType as ALL to get photos as well as video. I have not tried to get only video.

Comment: Ah I missed it. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Well it was my mistake! I needed to write mediaType and not MediaType.

Comment: @Neutralizer: your comment saved my day. its working now but no preview is available.